# Internet Explorer 10 'broken image'

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

For a random reason images refuse to load in IE10 (only on some requests).
When I look at the images report from the dev tools it says 'broken image'.
The images are just plain img tags and seem to work fine everywhere else.
Has anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Is it only for one page, or for any page you visit? Do you have a link to a page showing the issue?

Comment: Sadly I was not able to make an isolated test case out of it. Will try to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and it turned out that one of my delivered assets that was supposed to be a .jpg and had the .jpg file extension was ACTUALLY a .png! I changed the file extension (and of course, the file extension in the image path in my markup as well) and it worked just fine. Then I opened it up and exported it as a jpg, because that is what it should have been in the first place. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific example I can't really advise much, but I can tell you that I've been using IE10 for a while and I only ever have this issue when my computer is crashing from me abusing it to do massive amounts of calculations.

In general, it may help to get the image source and try loading it in a new tab. This may allow the browser to show a proper error page detailing the problem. Perhaps a header is being set wrong, for instance.

Another thing that would help is to look at the headers sent and received by using the Detailed View of the Network tab of the Developer Tools. If you notice anything out of the ordinary, this could be causing the issue.

For what it's worth, I've never heard of the dev tools just saying "broken image" like you describe, so really it would help if you could provide screenshots of the issue. All in all, however, it does sound more like a browser bug than a problem with your code, so it may be better suited on Microsoft's bug reporting site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer, but I have been experiencing this same issue.  A non-deterministic way to reproduce the issue is to go to imgur.com and being to open images in separate tabs. If you open ~10 images it is pretty certain that at least one will not load.  If all the images loaded, just keep opening more and this problem will pop up.  Additionally, this problem presents itself as dropped images within an animated .gif as well.